# How to search multiple values in postresql if the column type is jsonb

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem that I can't solve, so to speak.
For example, I will have an array of json data

As ex

```json
data = ['[{"Score":"300"}], [{"Color":"Blue"}]',
```

For example, with a single value, I receive results when I do a search in json

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE attributes @> '[{"Color":"Blue"}]';
```

I got results

But when I want to put it twice, I don't get it anymore

How could I proceed?

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE attributes @> ARRAY[[{"Score":"300"}], '[{"Color":"Blue"}]]';
```

No results

Comment: `['[{"Score":"300"}], [{"Color":"Blue"}]'`  isn't valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

The `@>` operator only works with JSON values, not with `jsonb[]`, so `array[...]` won't work - you need to provide a single JSON value on the right hand side.

It's unclear to me what your column really contains, but if you want to search for multiple elements in a single JSON array, you would need to do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE attributes @> '[{"Score":"300"}, {"Color":"Blue"}]';
```

That will return rows where the JSON array in the column `attributes` contains **both** JSON values. If you want to return rows that return at least one of them, you need an OR condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE attributes @> '[{"Score":"300"}]'
   OR attributes @> '[{"Color":"Blue"}]';
```